# Add items in loop to multidimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm attempting to add a couple of columns to a multidimensional PHP array inside a loop.
Inside the loop I currently have this:

```
$html[]['strongsNum'] = $strongsCode;
$html[]['wordNum'] = $wordNumber;
```

However, because I'm not setting the index manually, it creates two separate entries for the two.  How can I make it add the two columns to the one entry / row of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$html[] = array(
  'strongsNum' => $strongsCode,
  'wordNum' => $wordNumber,
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That definitely makes sense, since a multidimensional array is essentially an array within an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$html[] = array(
    'strongsNum' => $strongsCode,
    'wordNum' => $wordNumber
);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want to use the array(key => value) syntax:

After adding the initial 'strongsNum', you can re-access the last member of your array by using `count($myArray)-1` as the index.

```
$html[]['strongsNum'] = $strongsCode;
$html[count($html) - 1]['wordNum'] = $wordNumber;
```

Comment: I just want people to know that this is an option.